# test cases when accessing function using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am having a react-app where i am rendering button in one component and  model in another component . The button access the function `openModal` for opening the modal through refs. i am writing test cases for my application but could not figure out a way to write a test case for checking the modal is opening on button click

**Buttons component**

```
        <div>
          <button type='primary' onClick={() => this.handleClick.showModal()}>
            ADD 
          </button>
          <AddConceptModal ref={(instance) => this.handleClick = instance}/>
        </div>
```

**Modal component:**

```
    class ModalComp extends React.Component {
  state = {

    visible: false,

  }


  // show modal handles the logic of opening the modal
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { visible } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          visible={visible}
        >
          modal
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ModalComp
```

i tried creating instance like this:

```
let component = mount(<ModalComp />)
const instance = component.instance()
```

i even tried spyOn method in jest could do it exactly. how can i write test that simulate the button in button component which calls the showModal() and
i want to check if modal is receiving prop as true after button `click` simulation

Comment: Which test framework do you use ?

Comment: enzyme and jest